# Lighting socket hanging out from wall - is it fixable?

Tags: lighting

[image: Lighting socket hanging out from wall]

My lighting socket is hanging out from the wall and I suspect it is due to a thick layer of paint blocking the sides from clicking in. Is this fixable?

Comment: What part of the world are you located in?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Denmark

Comment: By the way I pulled the plastic cover off the front, the painter did a seriously bad job of painter over the socket.

Comment: Since you can get parts of it off, turn off the power and try scraping the paint away. Score the paint with a sharp knife to ensure that it doesn't flake away where you want to keep it.

Comment: @FreeMan ha! my thoughts too.

Answer (score 2):

If it is indeed the paint that's causing the stand-off, it would suffice to remove the paint.

If the stand-off is between base and wall:

With a utility knife and fresh sharp blade cut into the wall at the outline of the switch base. This scores the wall paint and prevents uncontrolled chipping in the next step: then, position the blade at an angle and carefully pry off the paint in the area covered by the switch ("under" the switch cover).

To avoid accidental damage to wires, let the blade extrude only 1..2mm from the knife.

If the stand-off is between base and switch: pry off the paint with a knife. Score it to make it easy to crack, and then pry it off in small sections.

Also make sure all threads in screw holes are clear of any paint.

If this is not the problem you meant, kindly provide more details in the question.

Comment: And here I am, the guy who often pokes people to write answers instead of comments. _hangs head in shame_

Comment: @P2000 It seems as though something is inside the socket pushing it outwards, or rather, not letting it stay in. Looks like a bundle of wires. How does these sockets usually stay attached to the wall?

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar, you'd have to shut off the power to this circuit, use a voltage tester to confirm the socket is dead, then carefully pull the socket out further letting the wires stretch out, and take pictures for us to see from multiple angles. Since the power is off, any wires coming loose won't be a hazard.

Comment: @P2000 Looks like this https://imgshare.io/image/241816797-539815813976358-5464707065779029383-n.pLbftg